# partitioning large signed networks

Tags: networkx, social-networking, weighted-graph, network-partitioning, pajek

I have a large signed network. The signed network is a weighted graph whose edges can be +1 or _1. I need to partition this graph so that most positive edges are placed inside the clusters and the negative edges are placed outside the cluster. this graph is very sparse.
 Do you have ideas?
there is a special version of Louvain algorithm for the signed network in Pajek.
Does anyone know about the details of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This paper](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.80.036115) by Vincent Traag outlines one approach.

He also has a python package (built on top of igraph) called [louvain](https://louvain-igraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can do this for you.

[This blog](https://www.traag.net/2015/03/03/powerblocs-social-balance-in-the-middle-east/) post demonstrates the package and method on an interesting use case.

Comment: Thank you Johannes Wachs

Comment: If this answers your question please accept the answer.